# How do you create a textnode with DOM that contains html elements like <br />?

Tags: dom, text

How do you create a textnode with DOM that contains html elements like br?

To get it like:

Hello DOM
more text

```
var brEl = document.createElement('br');
var pEl = document.createElement('p');
var sometext = "Hello DOM<br /> more text<br />";//not the way to do it
var sometext2 = "Hello DOM" + brEl + " more text" + brEl;//not the way to do it
pEl.appendChild(sometext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A textNode, by definition, contains only text. You need multiple textNodes interspersed with HTMLElementNodes.

```
var pEl = document.createElement('p');
pEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello DOM"));
pEl.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
pEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode("more text"));
pEl.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Comment: Ok thanks but why doesn't it work with the variable brEl like> pEl.appendChild(brEl);

Comment: @Chris_45 — It does … but if you append the same node multiple times then you will move it, not clone it.